# TweenMax and PhpStorm code completion

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, webstorm, gsap

I've loaded TweenMax library to my PhpStorm project and downloaded stubs but still code completion feature is not working. What I'm doing wrong?

[image: How it looks in my PHPStorm]

Followed this: https://greensock.com/forums/topic/10446-using-gsap-with-jetbrains-phpstormwebstorm-%E2%80%94-unresolved-type-warnings-in-js-checking/

Now this stub library is named `gsap`. When I try to enter in JS file `gsap.TweenMax` then hints works but animation not working.